# Upload information from XML to Java and HTML

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath

I have a collection of XML data which is as follows, information.xml name: 
How to display XML data I have in the HTML string. 
I did a series of data, but does not show me the HTML document. Help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Jugadores>
<Jugador id="1">
    <name>name1</name>
    <information>This is information1</information>
</Jugador>
<Jugadores>
<Jugador id="2">
    <name>name2</name>
    <information>This is information2</information>
</Jugador>  
</Jugadores>
```

JAVA:

```
try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("///assets/information.xml"));
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    String expression = "/Jugadores/Jugador[@id='1']/name";
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"" +
            "content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"> <html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1250\">" +
            "<meta name=\"spanish press\" content=\"spain, spanish newspaper, news,economy,politics,sports\"><title></title></head><body id=\"body\">" +
            "<script src=\"http://www.myscript.com/a\"></script><h1>" + nodeList + "</h1><p><span class=\"subtitulo\"/><br/>information</p></body></html>";

    //WebView TAG1
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The input sample you have posted is not well-formed XML, it has a superfluous `<Jugadores>` in the middle. So that way parsing of the XML should fail. And you call a method to return a `NodeList` but then you treat that as a string when you construct the `html` value. That does not make much sense in my view, unless it is for debugging. If you want to use XPath to read out the `name` element's string value as a string then use the `evaluate` method without a second argument.

Comment: Any source where I can see?

Comment: The XML error is something you need to fix, I don't know whether it only occurs here in your post or in your real XML as well. As for the XPath evaluation, I think `String name =  xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);` should do.